# Overflow with images not working

Tags: css

Hey so I can't seem to work the overflow with my image?
I've tried using a wrapper but the image doesn't seem to want to hide itself outside of the container?
I also tried using the z-index but that didn't seem to work either.

**html:**

```
<div id="hillcontainer"> 
    <img src="images\hilltop1.jpg" class="hill" alt="photo">
    <a href="hilltop.html"/></a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
div#hillcontainer{
    position: fixed;
    top:90px;
    left: 378px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px white solid;
    padding:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img.hill {
    position: fixed;
    top:70px;
    left: 400px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    /*transition:*/
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `position:fixed` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hfcfwLx9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why giving the `position:fixed` to the image ? This will do the same desired effect:

```css
div#hillcontainer{
  position: fixed;
  top:90px;
  left: 378px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px white solid;
  padding:20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img.hill {
  display:block;
  position: relative;
    width: 100%; // case you want to fit it, else remove the width

}
```

```html
<div id="hillcontainer"> 
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x150/000/fff"  class="hill" alt="photo"/>
  <a href="hilltop.html"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: So I want to have a container that holds the image in but cuts off some of the width so that when the  mouse hovers over it will move side to side. Just a cool transition effect. But the overflow doesn't appear to work.

Comment: then give it `position:absolute`